# Leaflet .locate watch option breaks .locate after changing tab Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, geolocation, leaflet

I have one function called loadmap(){} where im creating map.Im loading this function with

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
this.loadmap();


  }
```

Inside loadmap i have

```
  this.map = leaflet.map("map").fitWorld();
```

thats how i initialize map

This is how i remove map when user changes tab.

```
ionViewDidLeave(){

    this.map.remove();


  }
```

This is my .locate function:

```
var usermarker;


  this.map.locate({
    setView: true,
    maxZoom: 120,
    watch:true,
    enableHighAccuracy:true



  }).on("locationfound", e => {
    if (!usermarker) {
      usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(this.map);
  } else {
      usermarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
  }
}).on("locationerror", error => {
  if (usermarker) {
      this.map.removeLayer(usermarker);
      usermarker = undefined;
  }
});
```

The problem is in first time .locate function works.but if i change tab and go back to map tab .locate function doesnt work.if i remove watch option it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [`map.stopLocate()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stoplocate) besides `map.remove()`:

> Stops watching location previously initiated by `map.locate({watch: true})`

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/PKMPjfX3zD3QdWmEI0iX?p=preview (use the "Toggle map" button to simulate your changing tabs)

That being said, it is true that Leaflet could automatically do this when using the [`remove`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-remove) map method. => Merged in [PR Leaflet/Leaflet#5893](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5893)

Comment: thanks maybe they can add it in next versions.By the way i have one more problem.This error doenst accur on first load.It occurs after changing tabs.If user double clicks somewhere on map i get Cannot read property '_leaflet_pos' of undefined
error. do you have any idea ? thanks

Comment: i guess the reason is i should also remove html code when user changes tab  which is        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
 and add it when user comes back to map

Comment: If you need help for that issue, please feel free to open a new question, with all details to reproduce the problem.