# Cant reach this.map from a function leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, leaflet

What i am trying to do is locate user position on map every second.I know i can call  a function with `setInterval(function(),1000);`

I am initializing map with

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.map = leaflet.map("map").fitWorld();
    this.loadmap();
}
```

The problem is that I can't reach map from locate function.

```
function locate(){

var marker;

this.map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 120
}).on("locationfound", e => {
    if (!marker) {
        marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(this.map);
    } else {
        marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    }
}).on("locationerror", error => {
    if (marker) {
        map.removeLayer(marker);
        marker = undefined;
    }
});
}
```

If i delete function locate(); this.map.locate works but because i want to locate user everysecond to track their location i need to call .locate everysecond so i tried to put it in function an call that function with setinterval every second but its not working.Is there any way to locate user without puting .locate inside a function and calling it?

Comment: Hum, sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)…

Answer (score 0):

Although your question in not totally clear, if I understand correctly, you are trying to call your `locate` function as first argument of `setInterval`, but then you get an error message saying that `this.map` is undefined or something like that?

In that case, you just need to realize that `this` refers to the context of the function caller. When you use `setInterval` (same for `setTimeout`), the context is no longer your class instance object (the one that has `this.map`), but the global context. The problem is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem

There are several easy solutions, see [Referencing "this" inside setInterval/setTimeout within object prototype methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890685/referencing-this-inside-setinterval-settimeout-within-object-prototype-methods)

That being said, since you want to regularly track the user's position, why do not you just rely on the `map.locate`'s [`watch`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#locate-options-watch) option? If you are trying to workaround some issue (maybe [Leaflet .locate watch option breaks .locate after changing tab Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021405/leaflet-locate-watch-option-breaks-locate-after-changing-tab-ionic-3)?), there is a high chance you should fix that issue, rather than trying to workaround the symptoms.

Comment: watch option is just not working.it places marker to users first place when user moves marker doenst move it stays initial position.

Comment: You should investigate on `watch` option not working for you. It works fine for me on Chrome.